# Rangy ClassApplier and browserify

Tags: range, browserify, rangy

I'm using *browserify* to manage dependencies. `require('rangy')` seems to only *import rangy-core*, but not its sub-modules.

**How can I import rangy-classapplier?**

If I import the file `(require('./node_modules/rangy/lib/rangy-classapplier.js'))` it works, but I'd like to do it without having to include the file address.

Comment: Didn't you ask this a few days ago? I'm going to get to it soon.

Comment: Yes, I thought it went unnoticed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
require('rangy/lib/rangy-classapplier.js');
```

is what you want, at least as things are now. I don't see a neat way for me to make the path any simpler; I don't want to clutter the root directory. Possibly the `rangy-` prefix is unhelpful and I should get rid of it but I'll have a think about that.